# Como usar Join, mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, join

Estou começando com PHP agora, e gostaria de saber para que serve e como se usa o join, acho que iria ajudar a resolver o meu problema, mas não sei nem por onde começar...

Comment: O join pertence a linguagem sql e não ao php. Pode começar por aqui: [Qual é a diferença entre inner join e outer join?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/91)

Comment: Para resolver seu problema pode começar explicando e detalhando exatamente qual seu código e o que não funciona ;)

Comment: Eu ja fiz isso, e obtive ajuda, mas só queria me aprofundar mais sobre isso, Obrigado =)

Comment: Este artigo explica o relacionamento entre tabelas (importante para quem está começando), a utilização dos JOINs e suas variações: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/relacionamento-de-tabelas-no-mysql/